# polymorphic iterators in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, polymorphism

I'm trying to implement a polymorphic iterator in C++. Basically, I need this to be able to apply a filter, so that the iterator would skip some items depending on the associated condition. So I made a [GoF-like](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1407357&seqNum=4) iterator with an abstract interface, this allows me to derive a filtered iterator from it and implement the required logic. I also prefer interface-based iterators over templated ones as they allow to hide implementation without leading to a mess of duck-typed templates.

However, polymorphic iterators cannot be returned by value (as opposed to STL iterators), so I have to pass pointers around, and this can easily become dangerous like in this case, which seems logical but leads to a memory leak:

```
Iter* Collection::GetIter() {...} // new IterImpl
DoSomething(Iter*) {...} // doesn't do delete

DoSomething(Collection.GetIter()); // convenient, but wrong :\
```

The obvious solution is to use some kind of smart pointers to control iterators lifetime, but people often say that interfaces should be as simple and as general as possible, so smart pointers should probably be avoided there?

If you have worked with polymorphic iterators in C++, how was this issue resolved? Or are template-based iterators the only "good" way of iteration in C++? Thanks.

Comment: You can implement a filtering iterator quite easily in C++ without the iterator exposing any external polymorphism (Boost provides [a generic filter iterator](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html)).

Comment: Hmm, this reminds me of a question I once asked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3082995/129570.  Nothing to do with iterators, but with polymorphism and return-by-value.

Comment: @James McNellis: Yep, that's what I call the duck-typed mess :)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I see, and the only answer was to use smart-pointers... Sigh.

Comment: @7vies: Matthie M's answer on that question uses smart pointers, but as an implementation detail, not in the interface. So I don't think your objection about simple/general interfaces applies. Btw, if you prefer polymorphic iterators over duck-typing with templates, can I recommend Java? ;-p

Comment: @Steve Jessop: using smart pointers *is* very like Java or any other gc-based language, but with a lame garbage collector. And I just don't get it, runtime polymorphism doesn't exist anymore in C++? People don't care about coupling and compilation time, only about the runtime performance?

Comment: @7vies: it exists, however the STL has enforced a very strict model of Iterator that is quite incompatible with the GOF model :/

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Yes, by why would I need to use STL iterators for my containers if I'm not planning to use STL algrotihms on them anyway, especially with the poor support of lambdas, functors etc in C++03?

Comment: @7vies: if you want mark-sweep GC then, again, can I recommend Java? Or you could try Boehm's GC for C++. C++ iterators are designed with value semantics, and Matthieu's answer over on that other question is the "correct" idiom to bridge between value semantics and runtime polymorphism. Smart pointers in that case manage the allocated resource exactly as required. I don't really know what "lame" is supposed to mean - smart pointers handle this case fine. So what's the problem?

Comment: @7vies: "why would I need to use STL iterators for my containers if I'm not planning to use STL algrotihms on them anyway" - you don't have to use STL iterators. But you say you want to return by value, which means you have to implement value semantics. Which btw means using `shared_ptr` rather than `unique_ptr`, so that it's copyable, if you are starting from Matthieu's answer.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Oh come on, Java is far not garbage-collected-C++, why would you keep "recommending" it? "lame" is supposed to mean that when you use smart pointers in C++, it's like using a garbage collector, but a quite *limited* one. Ain't saying C++ is lame, or whatever, only this, sorry if you felt it some other, probably offensive way :)

Comment: @7vies: I'm not seriously recommending Java, just highlighting that C++ does things differently. If you want a GC you don't have to think about, you need to use a different language. If you want/have to use C++, then you need to think about resource management. The limits of smart pointers don't stop them working *for this purpose*, and the strategy+NVI idiom keeps the interface clean.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Well, I know the differences between C++ and Java and what resource management is, no need to highlight that for me, twice :) I expected that I've explained all my doubts, including usage of smart pointers in my question, apparently not...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual approach is to use compile-time polymorphism instead of runtime polymorphism; this allows the compiler many more opportunities to optimize code using the iterator and generally is more idiomatic in modern C++.

If you do need runtime polymorphic behavior, it's probably easiest to encapsulate the polymorphism within the iterator itself and not expose it externally.  You can accomplish this using a polymorphic function wrapper like `function`, found in Boost, C++ TR1, and C++0x.  I've provided an example here based on a filter iterator from one of my hobby projects:

```
template <typename ForwardIt>
class filter_iterator
    : public std::iterator<
          std::forward_iterator_tag, 
          typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type>

{
public:

    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type ValueType;
    typedef typename std::function<bool(ValueType)> FunctionType;

    filter_iterator() { }

    explicit filter_iterator(ForwardIt end)
        : it_(end), end_(end) 
    {
    }

    filter_iterator(ForwardIt it, ForwardIt end, FunctionType is_filtered) 
        : it_(it), end_(end), is_filtered_(is_filtered)
    { 
        skip_filtered_elements(); 
    }

    const ValueType& operator*()  const { return it_.operator*();  }
    const ValueType* operator->() const { return it_.operator->(); }

    filter_iterator& operator++()   
    { 
        ++it_; skip_filtered_elements(); return *this; 
    }

    filter_iterator operator++(int) 
    { 
        filter_iterator it(*this); ++*this; return it; 
    }


    friend bool operator==(const filter_iterator& lhs,
                           const filter_iterator& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.it_ == rhs.it_;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const filter_iterator& lhs,
                           const filter_iterator& rhs)
    {
        return !(lhs == rhs);
    }

private:

    void skip_filtered_elements()
    {
        while (it_ != end_ && is_filtered_(*it_))
            std::advance(it_, 1);
    }

    ForwardIt it_;
    ForwardIt end_;

    std::function<bool(const ValueType&)> is_filtered_;
};

template <typename ForwardIt>
filter_iterator<ForwardIt> make_filter_iterator(ForwardIt end)
{
    return filter_iterator<ForwardIt>(end);
}

template <typename ForwardIt, typename Function>
filter_iterator<ForwardIt> make_filter_iterator(ForwardIt it, 
                                                ForwardIt end, 
                                                Function f)
{
    return filter_iterator<ForwardIt>(it, end, f);
}
```

Usage is straightforward.  This example (using a C++0x lambda expression as the function type) demonstrates filtering odd numbers from a range:

```
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> x = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    std::copy(make_filter_iterator(x.begin(), x.end(), [](int i) { return i % 2; }),
              make_filter_iterator(x.end()),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: Don't you find it clunky that we need "two" iterators to implement any "smart" behavior ? I feel that Stepanov confused the "pointer" concept with the "iterator" one, and having to pass two items to be able to iterate safely makes for messed up interfaces :/

Comment: Only if that "smart" behaviour involves skipping elements.

Comment: @Matthieu: Yeah, it's pretty clunky. In my current project, I compose five filter, transform, and accumulation iterators in one place, and it makes me sad having to introduce a bunch of variables just to make the code readable (I don't have any runtime polymorphism, though; just lots and lots of compile-time polymorphism).

Comment: @Maxim: no. Any iterator that either need to "eat" several elements at a time or to implement a specific behavior on boundaries face this issue --> cyclic and accumulator come to mind.

Comment: @James: wow, you're pretty advanced, I played with `views` for a while but the mess of iteration made me cringe :/

Comment: @Matthieu:  If by "advanced" you mean "crazy," then yes, I am advanced.  :-)  There isn't anything too exciting in that project; it's a C Preprocessor implementation, so it has a transform iterator to convert raw characters into "source characters" that have line and column information, a filter iterator to do the newline splicing, and an accumulation iterator that tokenizes the source.  The only real downside to all of it (aside from source readability) is that when debugging some of the type names are longer than will fit across both of my 24" displays :-P.

Comment: @James McNellis: To comment on your answer, I see that indeed the current trend is to move nearly all polymorphism to compile time. I'm not a fan of that, though, mainly due to the awkward debugging. Templates tend to propagate - if you use them in one place you'll most probably have to use them in all others, while this is not the case with runtime polymorphism. Runtime polymorphism allows to truly hide the implementation, thus reducing coupling. It is simpler to understand and write algorithms on runtime polymorphic objects. And other reasons not fitting in the character limitations :)

Comment: @7ives:  Generic code (i.e., templates in C++) allows you to write code that is _very_ loosely coupled.  The STL is an excellent example of this:  there is no polymorphism in the STL at all, yet its components are far less coupled than those of practically any other library, and it uses design patterns that can easily be extended to code that you write (you can write your own iterators, containers, algorithms, and functions quite easily and use them with the existing STL components).

Comment: I do have to admit, though, I am not exactly an impartial judge on the usability of templates:  in my current project, I have one, 100 line .cpp file and upwards of 30 header files totalling some 4,000 lines of code, mostly templates.  I don't think the use of templates makes debugging harder, though; the Visual Studio debugger handles them rather well (I don't know how other debuggers perform w.r.t. templates; I only really use Visual C++).

Comment: @7vies: it's mostly a matter of taste, I guess. Template allow generic programming which is very pleasant, "hiding" implementation details (which I suppose mean reducing compilation dependencies) is not as necessary when you get some 30 cores for crunching it.

Comment: @James McNellis: It depends on how one defines "coupling". If you do everything on templates, then when using an iterator the compiler has to know it's *implementation*. Runtime polymorphism doesn't require you to know the implementation to use something, only its interface, and is in this sense less coupled. So when you are doing some high-level operation on templates, the compiler will have to know about *all* the objects that are being used, just to compile this piece of code. I'm talking about this kind of coupling, you probably mean something else.

Comment: @James McNellis: You are probably talking about coupling in the sense "this object can only be used with this type". In this sense, templated class are indeed less coupled between them. But "coupling" is not the only issue that I have with templates...

Comment: I am talking about coupling from the programmer's point of view:  how easy is it for me to repurpose the component? How modular and reusable is it? How easy is it for me to use it for multiple distinct tasks? I don't really care what the compiler does; it can do whatever it likes so long as I can write clean, generic, reusable code, and templates faciliate that readily (this is somewhat a lie: I _do_ care what the compiler does, but only because performance is important, and I know that the compiler can perform valuable optimizations with templates that it can't with polymorphic classes.)

Comment: If you want to write Java- or C#- or GOF-like iterators in C++, there's nothing wrong with that, but you are missing out on huge performance opportunities and you won't be able to use any of the standard library facilities.  If you don't care about performance and are willing to write your own libraries, then by all means go ahead.

Comment: @James McNellis: It's not always about performance, is it? For high-level operations I'm ready to trade performance for convenience, it won't have any noticeable effect on performance anyway. Of course I'm not going to use heap-allocated stuff in a tight loop, but why can't I use it in other places? If the standard library only supports the effective way (STL iterators and `container.end()`), but not the convenient and clear one (GoF iterators and `IsDone`), should I really stick to that "inconvenient" way?

Comment: @James McNellis: I'm also afraid that the things you "don't care" about will become a bottleneck in a big project - templates (at least in their current implementation) lead to quickly growing compilation dependencies, e.g. N*M cases for N algorithms on M types. With runtime polymorphism, it's only N cases applied to an interface which can be implemented by M types. And no implementation details.

Comment: @7vies:  our definition of "convenient" is different than mine.  :-) With the GoF iterators, you get a simpler interface but less flexibility (e.g., you get forward iteration only). With respect to performance, I don't mean small differences; I mean 10x performance differences: virtual function calls can rarely be inlined. You are right: sometimes it doesn't matter, but I tend not to pass up opportunities for easy performance gains, especially when it leads to more idiomatic code. I've never had major issues with complation time, even in very large projects (1M+ lines of code).

Comment: Like I said, if you prefer the GOF-style iterators, there isn't anything stopping you from implementing and using them in C++; you just lose out on all the advantages of using the STL.  My guess is that you prefer the GOF-style iterators because the STL iterators seem foreign and weird to you.  There's nothing wrong with that:  I prefer the STL style iterators because the GOF iterators seem foreign and limited to me.  I sincerely suggest, though, that you consider trying to use the STL iterators and learn to use them.  If you are going to program in C++, they come in very handy.

Comment: @James McNellis: No-no, I'm not that afraid of STL iterators. Well, I do some template programming myself and know what are traits, concepts, etc. However, there are issues with STL iterators, that other people have also mentioned, so it's not my personal fear. For example, mixed iteration and access or unsafe advance. STL iterators are just too much pointers for me. Any algorithm takes 2 iterators, and it doesn't make sense. STL iterators don't support infinite/lazy sequences. Just too many points I disagree with.

Comment: @James McNellis: I guess that with 1M+ lines of code the top-level code is not template-based, or is it? Do you still have some non-templated abstractions, or is "everything a template"? I just don't understand how you manage to stop the "template snowball" so that it does not require to include 1M lines of code to compile a single expression?

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues here:

- syntax: the STL assumes that iterators provide traits (`value_type`, `reference` for example) which need match the actual item.
- semantics: the iterators shall be copyable.

Remember that (in C++) an iterator is not a range, and therefore the `++` operation quickly gets messy, because you need to skip over some items, but (with a traditional implementation) you cannot know how many items are at your disposal.

Therefore, if you want polymorphic iterators which follow the GOF interface, you'll have to forgo the use of STL algorithms.

That said, it's perfectly feasible to implement polymorphic iterators:

```
struct IterBase
{
  virtual void increment() = 0;
  virtual void decrement() = 0;

  // others
};

class Iter
{
public:
  Iter& operator++() { base->increment(); return *this; }
  Iter operator++(int) { Iter tmp(*this); base->increment(); return tmp; }

  // others

private:
  std::unique_ptr<IterBase> base;
};
```

And then you'll need to write all the copy constructors, assignment operators and destructors to do the right thing.

Without template polymorphism though, it's only worth it if your iterator is only ever meant to be used on the same type.

Comment: GoF iterators know about the termination condition (eg `IsDone`). They are not STL-compatible, but I really don't see why would I need to run STL algorithms on them. Unfortunately there is no unique_ptr for me (C++03) ;( but I can try to emulate it. However, I still don't see if this is really better than just using a smart pointer, as this is by definition more complicated than a smart pointer - you have one as a member, and you can't hide its implementation as it's template-based, the only thing you can "hide" is its interface.

Comment: You can use a plain `scoped_ptr` in C++03 (as you won't need move semantics). The main advantage compared to a "single" smart pointer is that you can provide a reduced set of operations to override and then combine them in a lot of ways in the `Iter` class to provide a "true" interface (ie, usable by `.`). As for smart pointer being template-based... I think you're biaised ;)

Comment: @Matthieu M.: In which sense am I biased? :) I don't *hate* templates if you mean that. I only mentioned that this option is not an alternative to smart pointers but more like a wrapper on top of smart pointers, so it implies all possible issues related to smart pointers, not less.

Comment: @7vies: It implies the technical issues of smart pointers... but hides the functional ones (since they're wrapped). I don't know which technical issues a `scoped_ptr` has, for example. Anyway, you can always recode the smart pointer logic if you wish. The `Pimpl` idiom does not require their use, it merely ease the task to employ them, because they work.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: A possible "technical" issue of `scoped_ptr` is that you can't move it, only make a copy, while sometimes you actually want to move. I'm not sure what is a benefit of limiting access to the actual smart pointer that is used underneath, unless if this access somehow interfere with the functionality of the iterator itself... And by "recode" the smart pointer - do you mean creating my own smart pointers, instead of using the existing well-designed-and-tested ones?

Comment: @7vies:  You can "move" a `scoped_ptr` using `swap`.

Comment: @7vies: "recoding" --> I meant using a raw pointer and coding the logic by yourself (anyway you would have to implement the copy constructor by yourself, as it cannot be copied). Personally, I use a `pimpl` smart pointer that I coded myself for just this use :)

Comment: @James McNellis: Well, technically you can. But if you do, this leads to auto_ptr-like behavior with all those gotchas, which are only eliminated by using or emulating unique_ptr.

Comment: @James MCNellis said: *if you prefer the GOF-style iterators, there isn't anything stopping you from implementing and using them in C++; you just lose out on all the advantages of using the STL...* No, you can have both. Look at the implementations of `any_iterator` or `opaque_iterator` or similar approaches which add external polymorphism to duck-typed iterators. Even in your example, you have used the same "idiom": `std::function` is a polymorphic container which applies this to C++ callables, so you haven't avoided run-time polymorphism entirely... *Continued in next comment*

Comment: @James McNellis *...Continued from previous comment* Your example nicely demonstrates the problem of "propagation of duck-typing" (term just invented by me) - if you do not want or can't expose the type of source of the data (`ForwardIt`) then you're stuck: either you duck-type the data source too or you write some interface ( most probably a polymoprhic one) around it.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done using an iterator that contains a pointer in some form, and then passes on the functionality to the pointer.

You need to be very careful though doing this, and I have seen it done wrong many times (including falling for it myself once, then wondering why tests failed...)

- Do not use shared_ptr!

Fortunately I have not seen anyone above make the mistake of using shared_ptr, but it has the wrong semantics as when you copy an iterator you have 2 separate copies. But if they contain a shared_ptr and you advance one of the iterators, the other one will move with it - unexpected behaviour...

Therefore you need to clone every time you copy, but fortunately with C++0x you can just move much of the time rather than clone.

You also need to know that operations will hit the v-table for each iteration which may cause it to run slower than if you made the "macro" methods polymorphic (and implement perhaps with a template so you don't need to rewrite the code).

Comment: Thanks for raising the shared_ptr issue, good to have it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

A good solution I saw linked on Oli Charlesworth's question that didn't get much credit (at least, not as much as I thought it should).

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    SmartPointer<IteratorImplementation> ItrPtr;

    //Delegate methods to ItrPtr
}
```

You can then pass Iterator by value and defer methods to the contained smart pointer; It is basically an iterator that implements the 'Strategy' pattern, and the strategy exhibits the polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Looks like pimpl. The ugly thing about pimpl is the "delegate methods" part... And it is quite the same thing as a smart pointer.

Comment: @7vies: Right, but the user doesn't know they are dealing with a smart pointer, only an iterator.  Seemed cleaner to me than just passing back smart pointers to iterators...

Comment: @7vies: actually it's not the same. I've added more context in my own answer below, but the thing is that iterators have lots of redundancy in the methods they provide (variations on `++` for example) and thus you can actually reduce the number of methods to be overriden by the implementation of the `IterImpl` class.

Answer (score 0):

People do say that interfaces should be as simple and as general as possible. In your case, you describe a raw pointer as something that is not 'possible'. So, I'd suggest your obvious solution of using a smart pointer is the most simple and general technique that is possible.

To keep this smart pointer as simple and general as possible, I'd go with one of the stl provided smart pointers as they are the most ubiquitous.

Answer (score 0):

Been there.  Done that.

What you can do is hide your iterator interface behind another iterator.
Suppose that you have several kind of iterators that all hide behind the IIterator interface.

Then write another Iterator-like class, e.g. MyIterator, which contains a pointer to IIterator, and which simply forwards all calls to IIterator, like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyIterator
    {
    public:
       MyIterator() : m_iterator(nullptr) {}
       MyIterator(IIterator *it) : m_iterator(it) {}
       MyIterator &operator++()
          {
          if (m_iterator) m_iterator->operator++();
          return *this;
          }
       T &operator*() const
          {
          if (m_iterator) return m_iterator->operator*();
          else            throw an exception?
          }
    private
       IIterator *m_iterator;
    };
```

This example is far from complete, but you should get the idea.

Comment: It will have to manage lifetime somehow, so it's always the same smart pointer solution...