# IEnumerable in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator, enumeration

I'd like to know if there is a common way to represent high-level list-like objects in C++, **other than using STL iterators**. (by high-level I mean some complex objects, say a database response, as opposed to a low-level vector). Probably something similar to C#'s IEnumerable. If you have seen any projects using this, could you give me a reference? Thanks.

EDIT: Clarification why I'm interested in this, and not a part of the question. As asked in the comments, here is some code explaining the crucial difference that I see between compile-time polymorphism and run-time one. Imagine that you have a compile-time polymorphic type, which basically means that you have two types that have a common *concept* (not *interface*). If you want to apply an algorithm to this polymorphic type, it will *have* to be generic:

```
template<class iterator>
void myalgorithm(iterator iter) {...}
```

But when you have a run-time polymorphic type with an interface, say `IMyIterator`, you can write "normal", non-generic algorithms on it

```
void myalgorithm(IMyIterator* iter) {...}
```

The great difference in implementing these two functions is the different level of language and IDE support of working with interfaces vs generic types. Another point is that not everyone is that familiar with template programming, as probably you are. Finally, the second case allows to hide the implementation, while the first one is header-only. So please don't tell me that there is no difference between them, unless you can show me where I am wrong.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're averse to STL iterators?  Or is this just out of curiosity?

Comment: In managed C++, yes (it is the same interface you see in C# and VB.Net).  In standard C++, no (and you are better off using another language to handle database operations).

Comment: @templatetypedef: Both. If you are really interested, why, see *lots* of my comments there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852658/polymorphic-iterators-in-c

Comment: Why (not iterators)? They are the (contemporary) C++ way for iterable containers (even the C++0x "for each" construct uses them 'internally'!)

Comment: An example of your desired use case, please?

Comment: @eq-, @John Dibling: Well, I'll try to explain in a few words. The main reason is that I don't want to be forced and force the others here to write generic algorithms, which would be necessary in the case of generic iterators, filters etc. I don't need to run STL algorithms on them either. STL iterators is a very low-level concept (pointer-like), and does not generalize well (as opposed to e.g. generators). Implementing STL iterators is a pain (yes I know about boost.iterator). So I thought that if there is a common high-level concept, I could make use of it.

Comment: @7vies: I can only agree on the pointer-like vs generator and the pain that ensues :) Higher level languages spoil us :p

Comment: @7ives:  I'm confused.  You say you don't want to write generalized functionality or use a generic iterator, but you're asking about an `IEnumerable`-type gizmo.  `IEnumerable` is as generic as it gets.  Is genericity really the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Some code illustrating what you'd like to do would help clarify your question a bit.

Comment: @John Dibling: IEnumerable, even though a generic type, is an *interface*. An object implementing such interface can be treated by a common, non-generic algorithm, even though the object itself can still be polymorphic. All this is impossible with compile-time polymorphism. I'm not sure what code I could write to illustrate this idea.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: You don't agree to my "force the others here to write generic algorithms" point neither?

Comment: @7ives:  I guess what is confusing me is your statement that "this is impossible with compile-time polymorphism."  That statement is false.  If you could post code that shows it to be true, then I might be able to be of more help to you.

Comment: @John Dibling: Okay, I've updated the question, is it more clear?

Comment: @7vies: I love generic programming (and template, to an extent), so I can recognize the value of your argument, but I'll stick to using templates in my code when I can. By the way, one of the "real" arguments against template, is that they require compile-time knowledge of the types involved, which is incompatible with Factories in general.

Comment: @7ives:  Somewhat, but now you'ver made the question subhective & argumentativve.  whereas before I was hoping it was just a technical issue we could solve.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: The problem is that it's not exclusively "my" code, if it was I wouldn't hesitate to use templates :) For me, factories is just one example when a real run-time polymorphism is required, while there are many others. And it's not only a question of that real run-time polymorphism for me, as I also see other problems, some of which I've mentioned.

Comment: @John Dibling: It is a clarification, not the question. My actual question is before the "EDIT" part and is not subjective. If you could magically solve the points that I mentioned about the compile-time polymorphism, I would be happy, though.

Comment: @7ives: i wonder if youre really asking about reflection? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science)

Comment: @John Dibling: Wow, not at all, but I'm curious to know what made you think so. I don't really see the link between compile/run-time polymorphism and reflection.

Comment: @7ives:  i'll post something that might seem a bit like rambling :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SCARY iterators](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/SCARY.pdf). A database is one of the examples given of where SCARY iteration excels.

However, C#'s `IEnumerable<T>` is not really any different to an STL iteration, except that the polymorphism involved is at run-time, not compile-time. It shouldn't be tooo hard to write your own run-time polymorphism on top of it.

Comment: For me, the difference is huge. Algorithms on run-time polymorphic types are not required to be generic, while compile-time polymorphism can only be handled using generic algorithms. This changes completely the code, as if it is was written in some other language. So it's important at least. P.S. Thanks for the link, very interesting.

Comment: @7vies: Algorithms on run-time polymorphism are no different to those on compile-time polymorphism- you define an interface, then you implement it. Whether or not you define that interface as a compile-time concept or a run-time ABC doesn't change the fact that you're implementing an interface.

Comment: I wish this was true... But in practice compile-time polymorphism is way more complicated to implement then the run-time one (using type lists vs list of pointers to the interface is one simple example of that). Another difference is that run-time polymorphism allows to completely separate interface and implementation, while compile-time one is header-only. So I definitely don't agree that there is no difference :)

Comment: I've update the question with some more details on that, as I had a few similar comments.

Comment: I've read the paper you gave a link to, I still find it interesting, but not much more than that. The paper is dealing with a specific issue concerning polymorphic iterators and STL implementations, but is hardly a proof that "SCARY iteration excels" in some area.

Answer (score 1):

One example of an alternative would be [Qt4 introducing Java-Style iterators](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq12-qt4-iterators.html):

```
QList<int> list;
...
QListIterator<int> i(list);
while (i.hasNext())
    sum += i.next();
```

Comment: That's not fair, Qt is Qt and not really C++ :)

Comment: @Georg: Interestingly I prefer doing operations in the other order. Rather than having `bool hasNext() const` and `T next()`, I'd rather have `T get() const` and `bool next()`, because I might wish to "dereference" the item multiple times.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: That's how it is done in java, I'm pretty sure they had some good reasons to do it that way... or just did it wrong :)

Comment: @7vies: the interface I propose actually require 3 methods since you would also throw a `isValid` in the mix, so perhaps that minimizing the number of methods was a goal (as it simplifies the interface somewhat).

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Probably - that is what I thought of, too. Btw, the last time I thought about `isValid` I found this page and links therein quite interesting (as a general discussion, I don't do Java) http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IteratorSemanticsAreWrong so if you haven't seen it could be interesting for you too :)

Comment: @Matthieu: I agree on that approach, combined getter/iteration is something that takes getting used to. @7vies: Good one :D

Answer (score 0):

you can also see [Boost::FOR_EACH](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/foreach.html) it simplify the syntax of iteration.