# Dependency injection: templates (/generics) or virtual functions?

Tags: java, c++, generics, testing, polymorphism

This is a question of curiosity about accepted coding practices. I'm (primarily) a Java developer, and have been increasingly making efforts to unit test my code. I've spent some time looking at how to write the most testable code, paying particular attention to Google's [How to write untestable code](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-write-3v1l-untestable-code.html) guide (well worth a look, if you haven't seen it).

Naturally, I was arguing recently with a more C++-oriented friend about the advantages of each language's inheritance model, and I thought I'd pull out a trump card by saying how much harder C++ programmers made it to test their code by constantly forgetting the `virtual` keyword (for C++ers - this is the default in Java; you get rid of it using `final`).

I posted a code example that I thought would demonstrate the advantages of Java's model quite well (the [full thing is over on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/805922)). The short version:

```
class MyClassForTesting {
    private final Database mDatabase;
    private final Api mApi;

    void myFunctionForTesting() {
        for (User u : mDatabase.getUsers()) {
            mRemoteApi.updateUserData(u);
        }
    }

    MyClassForTesting ( Database usersDatabase, Api remoteApi) {
        mDatabase = userDatabase;
        mRemoteApi = remoteApi;
    }
}
```

Regardless of the quality of what I've written here, the idea is that the class needs to make some (potentially quite expensive) calls to a database, and some API (maybe on a remote web server). `myFunctionForTesting()` doesn't have a return type, so how do you unit test this? In Java, I think the answer isn't too difficult - we mock:

```
/*** Tests ***/

/*
 * This will record some stuff and we'll check it later to see that 
 * the things we expect really happened.
 */
ActionRecorder ar = new ActionRecorder();


/** Mock up some classes **/

Database mockedDatabase = new Database(ar) {

    @Override
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
        ar.recordAction("got list of users");
        /* Excuse my abuse of notation */
        return new Set<User>( {new User("Jim"), new User("Kyle")} );
    }

    Database(ActionRecorder ar) {
        this.ar = ar;
    }
}

Api mockApi = new Api() {

    @Override
    public void updateUserData(User u) {
        ar.recordAction("Updated user data for " + u.name());
    }

    Api(ActionRecorder ar) {
        this.ar = ar;
    }
}

/** Carry out the tests with the mocked up classes **/
MyClassForTesting testObj = new MyClassForTesting(mockDatabase, mockApi);
testObj.myFunctionForTesting();

// Check that it really fetches users from the database
assert ar.contains("got list of users");

// Check that it is checking the users we passed it
assert ar.contains("Updated user data for Jim");
assert ar.contains("Updated user data for Kyle");
```

By mocking up these classes, we inject the dependencies with our own light-weight versions that we can make assertions on for unit testing, and avoid making expensive, time-consuming calls to database/api-land. The designers of `Database` and `Api` don't have to be too aware that this is what we're going to do, and the designer of `MyClassForTesting` certainly doesn't have to know! This seems (to me) like a pretty good way to do things.

My C++ friend, however, retorted that this was a dreadful hack, and there's a good reason C++ won't let you do this! He then presented a solution based on Generics, which does much the same thing. For brevity's sake, I'll just list a part of the solution he gave, but again you can find [the whole thing over on Github](https://gist.github.com/807670).

```
template<typename A, typename D>
class MyClassForTesting {
    private:
        A mApi;
        D mDatabase;

    public MyClassForTesting(D database, A api) {
        mApi = api;
        mDatabase = database;
    }

    ...
};
```

Which would then be tested much like before, but with the important bits that get replaced shown below:

```
class MockDatabase : Database {
    ...
}

class MockApi : Api {
    ...
}

MyClassForTesting<MockApi, MockDatabase> 
    testingObj(MockApi(ar), MockDatabase(ar));
```

So my question is this: What's the preferred method? I always thought the polymorphism-based approach was better - and I see no reason it wouldn't be in Java - but is it normally considered better to use Generics than Virtualise everything in C++? What do *you* do in *your* code (assuming you *do* unit test) ?

Comment: Please change the title to make more sense.

Comment: Generics is a Java term, the correct term in C++ is templates

Comment: So you're looking for C++ experts to help you troll your C++ developer friends better? -> "Naturally, I was arguing recently with a more C++-oriented friend about the advantages of each language's inheritance model, and I thought I'd pull out a trump card by saying how much harder C++ programmers made it to test their code by constantly forgetting the virtual keyword"

Comment: @Rafe Kettler - Is this more descriptive? @Noah Roberts - The two systems of inheritance are very different, and naturally the design decisions involved are an interesting topic for debate. I'm asking C++ experts to help me understand what the preferred method is, and why.

Comment: I think this question boils down to, "use templates or use inheritance" (you can use both for *mocking*), traditional way is inheritance, though I prefer templates (it's compile time enforced and I like that), but that's my preference...

Comment: As I do both C++ and Java all day long, so I can say Java's system wins. If only because Google's Guice library which lets you bind at runtime each class's objects via the ctor, making testing Java code much easier then dealing with any C++ template mess you can come up with. :-)

Comment: @jelford: That's an interesting question for me - it seems that C++ is currently strongly biased towards "compile-time polymorphism" and people try to avoid run-time polymorphism at all cost, though for me this question is arguable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852658/polymorphic-iterators-in-c and some other questions of mine to see what I mean.

Comment: As the 'C++-oriented friend' in question, I think I should first address the memory leak issue: yes, that will cause a memory leak (actually, fail to compile) because you've copied my code wrong ;)  Get rid of 'new' and you're golden.

Comment: @thehouse: but with `new` it looks more like Java!.. (who cares if it compiles or not)

Comment: More importantly, there are really two debates going on here: Java's runtime-polymorphism vs C++ compile-time polym.  I think both are good and C++ has both.  I don't feel this is the real issue.  The massive problem I have with the Java code as posted was that it takes a `Database` parameter which is a type of _class_ and relies on the tester (or really anyone who wants to use a different database) to fake it my overriding it's entire implementation.  It should use an interface `IDatabase` from which all others inherit.

Comment: @thehouse: is Java's runtime polymorphism somehow different from C++'s runtime polymorphism (at the conceptual level), so that you call it specifically "Java's"?

Comment: @thehouse - It could be an abstract base class. Just add the `ar` field to the anonymous inner class and `Database` could well be an interface. As interfaces are the norm in Java, the `IInterface` naming convention is not used.

Comment: @7vies: No, not especially different.  I call it Java's because in Java it is the only way.  In C++ you have a choice.  But calling it Java's was misleading.

Comment: @OrangeDog: Why would you want to stop at abstract base class?  Is there functionality that you anticipate all Database implementations should share?

Comment: @thehouse - Probably not for this, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm probably biased, but I'd say the C++ version is better. Among other things, polymorphism carries some cost. In this case, you're making your users pay that cost, even though they receive no direct benefit from it.

If, for example, you had a list of polymorphic objects, and want to manipulate all of them via the base class, that would justify using polymorphism. In this case, however, the polymorphism is being used for something the user never even sees. You've built in the ability to manipulate polymorphic objects, but never really used it -- for testing you'll *only* have mock objects, and for real use you'll only have real objects. There will never be a time that you have (for example) an array of database objects, some of which are mock databases and others of which are real databases.

This is also much more than just an efficiency issue (or at least a run-time efficiency issue). The relationships in your code should be meaningful. When somebody sees (public) inheritance, that should *tell* them something about the design. As you've outlined it in Java, however, the public inheritance relationship involved is basically a lie -- i.e. what he *should* know from it (that you're dealing with polymorphic descendants) is an outright falsehood. The C++ code, by contrast, correctly conveys the intent to the reader.

To an extent, I'm overstating the case there, of course. People who normally read Java are almost certainly well accustomed to the way inheritance is typically abused, so they don't see this as a lie at all. This is a bit of throwing out the baby with the bathwater though -- instead of seeing the "lie" for what it is, they've learned to completely ignore what inheritance really means (or just never knew, especially if they went to college where Java was the primary vehicle for teaching OOP). As I said, I'm probably somewhat biased, but to to me this makes (most) Java code much more difficult to understand. You basically have to be careful to ignore the basic principles of OOP, and get accustomed to its constant abuse.

Comment: @OrangeDog - Could you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: In my experience the existence of all the different kinds of inheritance in C++ leads to issues when the wrong one is chosen (often a big walk up the multi-branched hierarchy to see what's virtual and what's not). Having started OOP in Smalltalk (the original), I see C++ as an abuse and Java as a lovely simple application of the concepts - especially with the Interface abstraction that C++ lacks.

Comment: @OrangeDog: it sounds a lot like the C++ you've dealt with was simply *really* badly designed. Anything involving a "big walk" is an instant tip-off to its having major problems -- a depth of more than 3 is rare in well-written C++. I used Smalltalk to, but also used some of its predecessors (Simula 67 and friends).

Comment: I won't disagree there. Some people let any monkey with an algorithm cookbook loose on large projects.

Comment: @JerryCoffin one issue I see here is having to templatize a class and, therefore, move the implementation into the header that wasn’t otherwise templatized. How do you deal with this?

Comment: @keelerjr12: Although it wasn't available when this answer was written, today I'd use a [module](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) instead of a header.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That makes sense. What about with a project using a version prior to C++20?

Comment: @keelerjr12: Given that we're basically just talking about two versions of the template (test and release) I'd probably generate a source file to explicitly instantiate the correct one at build time.

Answer (score 1):

Some key advice is "prefer composition to inheritence", which is what your `MyClassForTesting` has done with respect to the `Database` and `Api`. This is good C++ advice too: IIRC it is in *Effective C++*.

It is a bit rich for your friend to claim that using polymorphism is a "dreadful hack" but using templates is not. On what basis does (s)he claim that one is less hacky than the other? I see none, and I use both all the time in my C++ code.

I'd say the polymorphism approach (as you have done) is better. Consider that `Database` and `Api` might be interfaces. In that case you are explicitly declaring the API used by `MyClassForTesting`: someone can read the `Api.java` and `Database.java` files. And you are loosely coupling the modules: the `Api` and `Database` interfaces will naturally be the narrowest acceptable interfaces, much narrower than the `public` interface of any concerete class that implements them.

Comment: "templates" is polymorphism too, but resolved at compile-time. It is even more flexible and loosely coupled than the runtime polymorphism, as it does not necessarily need an interface - any class that behaves as required would go (i.e. duck typing). The problem is actually the opposite: this gives too much freedom, and *concepts* are supposed to add some interface-like restrictions. Moreover, run-time and compile-time polymorphism can be combined in both ways (RT using CT in implementation or CT calling a virtual function), and then the dependency question becomes even less clear :)

Comment: I (the friend) have no problem at all with polymorphism.  My objection is taking a concrete class as the parameter to MyClassForTesting and the overriding every one of its methods rather than taking an interface.  _That_ is a dreadful hack. You may have to follow the github link to see what the original code actually does wrong.

Comment: @thehouse: If the point is about using interfaces versus overriding virtual functions of concrete classes, why does the question say about templates versus polymorphism? This is confusing.

Comment: @7vies: Because life ain't that nicely packaged.  We were having a discussion that turned out to involve two orthogonal issues.  I'm not sure jelford realised this when he posted but that's just how the cookie crumbled.

Comment: @thehouse I totally agree that the "correct" solution is to use an interface (or pure virtual, in C++-land), but I think we already know that we can't trust our devs to always do what's "best" for testing.

Answer (score 1):

More importantly, you cannot create templated virtual functions. This makes it impossible to test functions in C++ which use templates, by using inheritance, and therefore testing by inheritance in C++ is unreliable as you cannot test all classes that way, and definitely not every use of a base class can be substituted with that of a derived class, especially w.r.t instantiating templates of them. Of course, templates introduce their own problems, but I think that's beyond the scope of the question.

You're throwing inheritance at the problem but really it's not the right solution- you only need to change between the mock and the real at *compile* time, not at *run* time. This fundamental fact makes templates the better option.

In C++, we don't forget the virtual keyword, we just don't need it, because run-time polymorphism should only occur when you need to vary the type at *run-time*.  Else, you're firing a rocket launcher at a nail.

Comment: "you cannot create templated virtual functions" - ooooo, now, let's be careful.  You cannot create a virtual method that is _itself_ a template.  Template classes, however, can quite happily have virtual methods.

Comment: @thehouse: What I said is not even remotely ambiguous. It doesn't mention classes anywhere, or even think about suggesting that templated classes cannot have virtual functions.

Comment: "run-time polymorphism should only occur when you need to vary the type at run-time" - this could be true if the only difference of run-time polymorphism was its "runtimeness". But it is by far not the only issue.

Comment: @7vies: Of course, templates bring their own problems, which I did mention briefly. I'm not trying to suggest that they are some kind of wonder-solution. They are, however, the appropriate solution to this specific problem.