# Inheritance in curiously recurring template pattern polymorphic copy (C++)

Tags: c++, polymorphism, crtp

I'm using CRTP to add a clone method to inherited classes, for example:

```
class Base 
{
     virtual ~Base() {};
     virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
}; 

template<class Derived> class BaseCopyable : Base
{ 
public:
    virtual Base* clone() const
    {
        return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const&>(*this));
    }
};

class A : public BaseCopyable<A>;
class B : public BaseCopyable<B>;
etc...
```

But if I have a class that inherits from B, for example:

```
class differentB : public B;
```

Then clone() doesn't return an object of type differentB, it returns a B. Besides writing a new clone() method in differentB, is there some way to fix this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You could just demand that only the most-derived class inherit from `BaseCopyable`.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of a clone member function that you can return the derived type in an override in the derived? This is called `covariant return types` and a perfect fit for the feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rework of my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10443637/1362568)

Your intent is to have all the derived classes in your hierarchy
inherit cloneability (polymorphic copy) from their base class so
that you do not also need to provide each of them with an override
of `clone()`, but your attempted CRTP solution with class template
`BaseCopyable` can only only confer cloneability in this way upon
classes immediately derived from `Base`, and not upon classes derived
from such derived classes.

I do not think it is not possible to propagate cloneability right down an
arbitrarily deep hierarchy by confering cloneability "just once" at
the topmost concrete classes. You must explicitly confer it on each
concrete class, but you *can* do this via their base classes and
without repetitiously overriding `clone()`, by using a CRTP
template that relays cloneability from parent class to child in the
hierarchy.

Clearly, a CRTP template that fits this bill will differ from `BaseCopyable`
by requiring *two* template parameters: the parent type and the child type.

A C++03 solution is as illustrated  by the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

// As base of D, this makes D inherit B and makes D cloneable to
// a polymorphic pointer to B
template<class B, class D>
struct cloner : virtual B
{
    virtual B *clone() const {
        return new D(dynamic_cast<D const&>(*this));
    }
    virtual ~cloner() {}       
};

struct Base 
{
    virtual ~Base() {
         std::cout << "I was a Base" << std::endl;
    };
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
}; 

struct A : cloner<Base,A> // A inherits Base
{
    virtual ~A() {
         std::cout << "I was an A" << std::endl;
    };
};

struct B : cloner<Base,B> // B inherits Base
{
    virtual ~B() {
         std::cout << "I was a B" << std::endl;
    };
};

struct DB : cloner<B,DB> // DB inherits B, Base
{
    virtual ~DB() {
         std::cout << "I was a DB" << std::endl;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Base * pBaseA = new A;
    Base * pBaseB = new B;
    Base * pBaseDB = new DB;
    Base * pBaseCloneOfA = pBaseA->clone();
    Base * pBaseCloneOfB = pBaseB->clone();
    Base *pBaseCloneOfDB = pBaseDB->clone();
    B * pBCloneOfDB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pBaseDB->clone());
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseA" << std::endl; 
    delete pBaseA;
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseB" << std::endl;
    delete pBaseB;
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseDB" << std::endl;
    delete pBaseDB;
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseCloneOfA" << std::endl;
    delete pBaseCloneOfA;
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseCloneOfB" << std::endl; 
    delete pBaseCloneOfB;
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseCloneOfDB" << std::endl;    
    delete pBaseCloneOfDB;
    std::cout << "deleting pBCloneOfDB" << std::endl;   
    delete pBCloneOfDB;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
deleting pBaseA
I was an A
I was a Base
deleting pBaseB
I was a B
I was a Base
deleting pBaseDB
I was a DB
I was a B
I was a Base
deleting pBaseCloneOfA
I was an A
I was a Base
deleting pBaseCloneOfB
I was a B
I was a Base
deleting pBaseCloneOfDB
I was a DB
I was a B
I was a Base
deleting pBCloneOfDB
I was a DB
I was a B
I was a Base
```

Provided that all the classes involved are default constructible, `B`
need not be a *virtual* base of `cloner<B,D>` and you can remove the `virtual`
keyword from `struct cloner : virtual B`. Otherwise, `B` must be a virtual base 
so that a non-default constructor of `B` can be called by a constructor of `D`,
although `B` is not a direct base of `D`.

In C++11, where we have variadic templates, you can do without virtual
inheritance altogether by furnishing `cloner<B,D>` with an "all-purpose"
template constructor through which it can forward arbitrary constructor
arguments from `D` to `B`. Here is an illustration of that:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class B, class D>
struct cloner : B
{
    B *clone() const override {
        return new D(dynamic_cast<D const&>(*this));
    }
    ~cloner() override {}
    // "All purpose constructor"
    template<typename... Args>
    explicit cloner(Args... args)
    : B(args...){}  
};

struct Base 
{
    explicit Base(int i)
    : _i(i){}   
    virtual ~Base() {
         std::cout << "I was a Base storing " << _i << std::endl;
    };
    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
protected:
    int _i;
}; 

struct A : cloner<Base,A>
{
    explicit A(int i)
    : cloner<Base,A>(i){}
    ~A() override {
         std::cout << "I was an A storing " << _i << std::endl;
    };
};

struct B : cloner<Base,B>
{
    explicit B(int i)
    : cloner<Base,B>(i){}
    ~B() override {
         std::cout << "I was a B storing " << _i << std::endl;
    };
};

struct DB : cloner<B,DB>
{
    explicit DB(int i)
    : cloner<B,DB>(i){}
    ~DB() override {
         std::cout << "I was a DB storing " << _i << std::endl;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Base * pBaseA = new A(1);
    Base * pBaseB = new B(2);
    Base * pBaseDB = new DB(3);
    Base * pBaseCloneOfA = pBaseA->clone();
    Base * pBaseCloneOfB = pBaseB->clone();
    Base * pBaseCloneOfDB = pBaseDB->clone();
    B * pBCloneOfDB = dynamic_cast<B*>(pBaseDB->clone());
    std::cout << "deleting pA" << std::endl; 
    delete pBaseA;
    std::cout << "deleting pB" << std::endl;
    delete pBaseB;
    std::cout << "deleting pDB" << std::endl;
    delete pBaseDB;
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseCloneOfA" << std::endl;
    delete pBaseCloneOfA;
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseCloneOfB" << std::endl; 
    delete pBaseCloneOfB;
    std::cout << "deleting pBaseCloneOfDB" << std::endl;    
    delete pBaseCloneOfDB;
    std::cout << "deleting pBCloneOfDB" << std::endl;   
    delete pBCloneOfDB;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
deleting pA
I was an A storing 1
I was a Base storing 1
deleting pB
I was a B storing 2
I was a Base storing 2
deleting pDB
I was a DB storing 3
I was a B storing 3
I was a Base storing 3
deleting pBaseCloneOfA
I was an A storing 1
I was a Base storing 1
deleting pBaseCloneOfB
I was a B storing 2
I was a Base storing 2
deleting pBaseCloneOfDB
I was a DB storing 3
I was a B storing 3
I was a Base storing 3
deleting pBCloneOfDB
I was a DB storing 3
I was a B storing 3
I was a Base storing 3
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to propagate the base through the whole inheritance
hierarchy, but I don't think this will be particularly useful as for
every further derived class you now get a whole new hierarchy and all
the polymorphism is going to be for naught.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base 
{
public:
     virtual ~Base() {};
     virtual Base* clone() const = 0;
}; 

template<class Derived> class BaseCopyable : Base
{ 
public:
    virtual Base* clone() const
    {
        return new Derived(static_cast<Derived const&>(*this));
    }
};

struct Default;

template<typename Self, typename Arg>
struct SelfOrArg {
  typedef Arg type;
};

template<typename Self>
struct SelfOrArg<Self, Default> {
  typedef Self type;
};

template<typename Derived = Default>
class A : public BaseCopyable< typename SelfOrArg<A<Derived>, Derived>::type >
{

};

class derivedA : A<derivedA> {

};
```

Although this still has the drawback of the broken return type for
`BaseCopyable`. With a classic `virtual constructor` idiom, you get
the ability to say something like:

```
void func(Derived& d) {
  // thanks to covariant return types Derived::clone returns a Derived*
  Derived* d2 = d.clone();
  delete d2;
}
```

This wont be possible with your scheme, although easily possible
through adjusting the return type in `BaseCopyable`.

Just write a macro to get rid of the boilerplate :)