# C++ Cloneable mixin

Tags: c++, clone, mixins

I have several classes that need the following `clone` function to be defined:

```
struct Base
{
  virtual Base * clone() const = 0;
};

struct A : public Base
{
    Base * clone() const {
      return new A(*this);
  }
};

struct B : public Base
{
    Base * clone() const {
      return new B(*this);
  }
};

struct X : public Base2
{
    Base2 * clone() const {
      return new X(*this);
  }
};
```

I am trying to do this with a Cloneable mixin to avoid this redundant code:

```
template <typename BASE, typename TYPE>
class CloneableMixin
{
public:
  BASE*clone() const {
    return new TYPE( dynamic_cast<const TYPE &>(*this) );
  }
};

struct A : public Base, public CloneableMixin<Base, A>
{
};
```

<del>However, this doesn't work, because in `new TYPE(*this)` from `CloneableMixin`, `*this` is of type `CloneableMixin<BASE, TYPE>`.</del>

**Update:** the `CloneableMixin` can `dynamic_cast` to the correct type. But now I have another problem: `CloneableMixin::clone` doesn't successfully override `Base::clone`, and so the compiler reports A is a abstract type.

Can some clever use of `virtual` inheritance allow `CloneableMixin::clone` to override `Base::clone`? Is there some macro I should use for this?

Do you know of a way around all of this redundant code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422760/inheritance-in-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-polymorphic-copy-c

Comment: `Base::clone` needs to be `virtual` in order for `=0` to be valid.

Comment: @rhalbersma I'm not sure if it's quite the same. Not all of my cloneable classes will have the same base type (e.g. `Base`, `Base2`).

Answer (score 7):

> Can some clever use of virtual inheritance allow CloneableMixin::clone to override Base::clone?

Your `CloneableMixin<Base,Derived>` cannot override any method of `Base` - either
polymorphically or by hiding - because `CloneableMixin<Base,Derived>` is
not derived from `Base`.

On the other hand, if `CloneableMixin<Base,Derived>` *were* derived from `Base`
you would no longer have any need for it to be a mixin, because -

```
class Derived : public CloneableMixin<Base,Derived> {....};
```

would inherit `Base`.

So for the needs of your example the solution illustrated here will suffice:

```
#include <iostream>

// cloner v1.0
template <class Base, class Derived>
struct cloner : Base
{
    Base *clone() const override {
        return new Derived( dynamic_cast<const Derived &>(*this) );
    }
    ~cloner() override {};
};

struct Base
{
    virtual Base * clone() const = 0;
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Base()" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~Base() {
        std::cout << "~Base()" << std::endl;
    }
};


struct A : cloner<Base,A> 
{
    A() {
        std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
    }
    ~A() override {
        std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    Base * pb = a.clone();
    delete pb;
}
```

(If you are compiling to the C++03 standard rather than C++11, then you may
simply delete the occurrences of the `override` keyword.)

This solution will break down for some more real-worldly class hierarchies,
e.g. in this illustration of the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// cloner v1.0
template<class B, class D>
struct cloner : B
{
    B *clone() const override {
        return new D(dynamic_cast<D const&>(*this));
    }
    ~cloner() override {}       
};

/*  Abstract base class `abstract` keeps the state for all derivatives
    and has some pure virtual methods. It has some non-default
    constructors. 
*/
struct abstract 
{
    virtual ~abstract() {
        cout << "~abstract()" << endl;
    }
    int get_state() const {
        return _state;
    }
    void run() {
        cout << "abstract::run()" << endl;
        a_root_method();
        another_root_method();
    }
    virtual void a_root_method() = 0;
    virtual void another_root_method() = 0;
    virtual abstract * clone() const = 0;

protected:

    abstract()
    : _state(0) {
        cout << "abstract(): state = " << get_state() << endl;
    }
    explicit abstract(int state) : _state(state) {
        cout << "abstract(" << state << ") : state = " 
        << get_state() << endl;
    }   
    int _state;
};

/*  Concrete class `concrete` inherits `abstract`
    and implements the pure virtual methods.
    It echoes the constructors of `abstract`. Since `concrete`
    is concrete, it requires cloneability. 
*/
struct concrete : cloner<abstract,concrete> 
{   
    concrete() { 
        cout << "concrete(): state = " << get_state() << endl;
    }
    explicit concrete(int state) : abstract(state) {  //<- Barf!
        cout << "concrete(" << state << ") : state = " 
            << get_state() << endl;
    }
    ~concrete() override {
        cout << "~concrete()" << endl;
    }
    void a_root_method() override {
        ++_state; 
        cout << "concrete::a_root_method() : state = " 
            << get_state() << endl;
    }
    void another_root_method() override {
        --_state;
        cout << "concrete::another_root_method() : state = " 
            << get_state() << endl;
    }       
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    concrete c1;
    unique_ptr<abstract> pr(new concrete(c1));
    pr->a_root_method();
    pr->another_root_method();
    unique_ptr<abstract> pr1(pr->clone());
    pr1->a_root_method();
    return 0;
}
```

When we attempt to build this, the compiler will give an error at
the initialization `abstract(state)` in the constuctor of `concrete` (at the `Barf!`
comment), saying:

```
error: type 'abstract' is not a direct or virtual base of 'concrete'
```

or words to that effect. Indeed, the direct base of `concrete` is not `abstract`
but `cloner<abstract,concrete>`. However, we cannot rewrite the constructor as:

```
/*Plan B*/ explicit concrete(int state) : cloner<abstract,concrete>(state){....}
```

Because there is has no such constructor as

```
cloner<abstract,concrete>::cloner<abstract,concrete>(int)
```

But the compiler's diagnostic suggests a fix. *This* is were virtual
inheritance can help. We need `abstract` to become a *virtual* base of `concrete`, which
means effectively "an honorary direct base of `concrete`", and we can achieve that 
just by making `B` a *virtual* base of `cloner<B,D>`:

```
// cloner v1.1
template<class B, class D>
struct cloner : virtual B
{
    B *clone() const override {
        return new D(dynamic_cast<D const&>(*this));
    }
    ~cloner() override {}       
};
```

With that, we have a clean build and output:

```
abstract(): state = 0
concrete(): state = 0
concrete::a_root_method() : state = 1
concrete::another_root_method() : state = 0
concrete::a_root_method() : state = 1
~concrete()
~abstract()
~concrete()
~abstract()
~concrete()
~abstract()
```

There are good reasons to be wary of virtual inheritance on principle
and to reserve its use for at least for cases in which it has architectural
rationale - not for workarounds, as we have used it just now.

If we prefer to do without virtual inheritance for this problem, then we
must somehow ensure that there is a constructor of `cloner<B,D>` that
echoes *any* constuctor of `B`, for arbitrary `B`. Then any corresponding
constructor of `D` will be able to initialize its direct base `cloner<B,D>`
whatever the arguments are.

This is a pipedream for C++03, but with the magic of variadic template
parameters in C++11 it is easy:

```
// cloner v1.2
template<class B, class D>
struct cloner : B
{
    B *clone() const override {
        return new D(dynamic_cast<D const&>(*this));
    }
    ~cloner() override {}
    // "All purpose constructor"
    template<typename... Args>
    explicit cloner(Args... args)
    : B(args...){}  
};
```

With this, we *can* rewrite the `concrete` constructor as `/*Plan B*/`, and
again we have a correct build and executable.

Comment: P.S. Compilation was with GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2

Answer (score 0):

During the instantiation of your Cloneable mixin, the derived class is still in an incomplete type. You could try to add the proverbial extra leval of indirection like this:

```
template 
<
    typename Derived
>
class Cloneable 
:    
    private CloneableBase
{
public:
    Derived* clone() const
    {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this->do_clone());
    }

private:
    virtual Cloneable* do_clone() const
    {
        return new Derived(static_cast<const Derived&>(*this));
    }
};

class CloneableBase
{
public:
    CloneableBase* clone() const
    {
        return do_clone();
    }

private:
    virtual CloneableBase* do_clone() const=0;
};

class MyClass: public Cloneable<MyClass>;
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. In my case, A <- B <- C <- D. A is the base class (abstract), B is an abstract class too. C and D are concrete classes. A declares `virtual A* clone() const = 0;` and B does similar. When I let C <- Cloneable<C>, GCC says `undefined reference to 'vtable for C'`. The code works fine if I implement it by hand (not using templates). [ GCC 4.5.3, Cygwin ]

Comment: @AsukaKenji-SiuChingPong- Could you provide a LiveWorkspace example to show your code?