# how to allocate memory for specify type in polymorphism?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an abstract class that 3 other classes inherit from that and they are concrete classes. I have a pointer of type abstract class. I want to write a function, which receives an object of one of the 3 classes I mentioned, and then allocate memory for that (with base class pointer) and then assign the value of passed object to it. How can I `new` memory for that special type in my function?
(I don't know the type of the object I have received. I only know it inherits from my abstract class)

thanks.

Comment: How do you not know the type passed to the function?  Are you passing a base class pointer?  If so it sounds like what you need is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255546/c-deep-copying-a-base-class-pointer

Comment: Maybe some sample code could be usefull to ilustrate your answer...

Comment: If that function already receives an object, why do you want to allocate memory?

Comment: Have you considered implementing the clone pattern instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148706/copying-a-polymorphic-object-in-c

Comment: This is what `clone` function is for.

Comment: @displayname It seems to me OP is trying to copy the given object.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That would make sense. Maybe she wants to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would solve this problem is that I would add a `duplicate()` method to the abstract base class, and I would implement it in each of the derived classes.  Each implementation knows exactly how large it is, so it can use `new` to allocate the memory.  It also knows exactly what content it has, so it can assign its value to the new instance.  Nice, simple, elegant. and object-oriented.

Comment: can you explain me more?? the return type of duplicate () must be "base class *" ??

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for you.

1. Clone an object of the derived type.
2. Create a default-constructed object of the derived type.

Both of them can be implemented using `virtual` member functions.

You can see [C++: Deep copying a Base class pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255546/c-deep-copying-a-base-class-pointer) on how to clone an object.

You can follow a similar path to return a default-constructed object.

```
struct base {
   virtual ~base() {}                // Remember to provide a virtual destructor
   virtual base* make_new() const = 0;
};
struct derived : base {
   virtual derived* make_new() const {
      return new derived(); // Return a default-constructed object.
   }
};
```

Add then call `make_new()` on the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of solving it is to add a `clone` member function that each class overrides. That can be a bit boiler-plate-ish however, so if you aren't afraid of templates you can automate the process:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Abstract {
    virtual ~Abstract() = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Abstract> clone() const = 0;
    virtual void                      speak() const = 0;
};

template<class C>
struct Cloneable : Abstract {
        std::unique_ptr<Abstract> clone() const override {
            return std::make_unique<C>(*(C*)this);
        }
};

struct Concrete : Cloneable<Concrete> {
    void speak() const override {
        std::cout << "Concrete";
    }
};

void foo(Abstract& a) {
    a.clone()->speak();
}

int main() {
    Concrete c;
    foo(c);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://ideone.com/G82Mzp)</kbd>

It works out of the box for copy-able classes. And if your class isn't copy-able, you can just override `clone` yourself, and do the thing that makes sense.