# Residing a member of parent class type inside another class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual, class-design

```
#include <iostream>

class BarParent
{
    virtual void fuz()
    {
        std::cout << "BarParent" << std::endl;
    }
};

class BarChild : public BarParent
{
    virtual void fuz()
    {
        std::cout << "BarChild" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Foo
{
// ??BarParent bar;??
public:
    Foo(BarParent bar);
};
```

What I seek is to store a **copy** of `BarParent` that is passed to the constructor and let it reside in `Foo`, while still calling the correct `virtual function`

This is an embedded application: Use of the heap is frown upon. So preferably, no heap

**SUMMARY**: To the best of knowledge, it cannot be done, becuase of the [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) (long story short the compiler cannot determine the size of generic `Bar` and so on copying it type casts), so polymorphism cannot be achieved. Using templates might be a good idea, however, it defines multiple `class`es `Foo<typename BarType>`, as a result, doing a `function` such as `changeBar(BarParent)`, would not be possible since the compiler would define this as `changeBar(BarType)` defined only for class `Foo<Bartype>`. If someone has a better idea, please let me know.

I think i will have to go for heap, or `const Barparent` and pointers. If the user `const_cast`s, then he is asking for trouble, not my fault!

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo
{
    BarParent* bar; //or std::unique_ptr<>
public:
    Foo(BarParent* barInst):bar(barInst){}
};
```

This will do what you want it to. You store a pointer to a `BarParent` object and you can polymorphicaly(is that a word?) call virtual functions using it.

You need to create the copy outside the constructor (on the heap or otherwise), and pass the pointer to it to the `foo` object constructor. Alternatively you can implement a clone method as discussed at [Copying derived entities using only base class pointers, (without exhaustive testing!) - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027456/copying-derived-entities-using-only-base-class-pointers-without-exhaustive-tes)

A **radically different approach** would be to use **templates**.. it would leave you with a multidudes of `foo<>` types though.. If you are not going to reassign the `bar` object, or store all `foo` in a container, this might be the better option for you, since it doesn't involve the heap

```
template<typename BarType>
class Foo
{
    BarType bar; //pointer not needed any more since we are storing the exact type.
public:
    Foo(BarType& barInst):bar(barInst){}
};
```

Comment: But the object `BarParent` can be edited under some other alias in a higher scope. I don't want that. I need to __copy__ it

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of to handle this gracefully without [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

The only way I could think of would be to use pointer, and create a copy when "calling" the `Foo` constructor:

```
class Foo
{
    BarParent* bar;

public:
    Foo(BarParent* b) : bar(b) {}
};

BarChild child;

Foo myFoo(new BarChild(child));
```