# C++ how to move object to a nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, move

I am thinking a strange use case where I want to move an object to a nullptr. Maybe I should give an code fragment:

```
class Objpair {
   public:
      Objpair(Obj&& a, Obj&&b) : first(&a), second(&b) { }
   private:
       Obj* first;
       Obj* second;
};
```

The problem is that when a and b is out of scope, the first and second pointer will be dangling.  If I can move Object a onto the first pointer then there should be no problem of double free and scoping issues.  If the member first were declared as Obj not Obj* pointer, then the straight first(std::move(a)) would do the job. I must be doing something wrong here.  I am thinking of move instead of copying because I am trying to transfer of control from another object to the current object and improve on performance.

The pointer version is used because I am thinking about polymorphic behavior for the member object.

Comment: *If the member first were declared as Obj not Obj** *pointer, then the straight first(std::move(a)) would do the job.* Why aren't you following that?

Comment: What's the sense in storing the addresses of rvalue expressions? `a` and `b` are objects that are probably about to die. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: first and second can point to BaseClass, Derived1, Derived2, ...

Comment: *"moving into an uninitialized pointer"* makes no sense to me. You need to have an actual `Obj` to move into it. *"when a and b is out of scope, the first and second pointer will be dangling"* Not when `a` and `b` are destroyed. When objects you used to initialize them are destroyed.

Comment: The fragment is wrong, somehow not making that clear.  As mentioned, should not use that. Looking for a better design.

Comment: In a multi-threaded environment, one part of the code makes some objects; another part of the code picks them up and compose them into a different type.  I could do with pointer version.  Just seeking possibility of using object reference and convert pointers. Is such syntax even possible in C++.

Comment: @KeminZhou it's rather hard to tell what you're trying to achieve. I'm worried that this is either an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) or that you're trying to do premature optimization. Could you elaborate on the _overall_ problem that you're trying to solve, and why it led you to try this design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is *move construct* objects from your parameters like this:

```
class Objpair {
   public:
      Objpair(Obj&& a, Obj&& b)
      : first(new Obj(std::move(a)))
      , second(new Obj(std::move(b)))
      {}

   private:
       Obj* first;
       Obj* second;
};
```

I recommend you use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
class Objpair {
   public:
      Objpair(Obj&& a, Obj&& b)
      : first(std::make_unique<Obj>(std::move(a)))
      , second(std::make_unique<Obj>(std::move(b)))
      {}

   private:
       std::unique_ptr<Obj> first;
       std::unique_ptr<Obj> second;
};
```

Comment: The construction will be a move-construction without the need for `std::move()`, since the ctor gets rvalue references to begin with.

Comment: @einpoklum No you need to `std::move` because once the *r-value-references* are bound they become *l-value-references*. You have to either `std::move` or `std::forward` (for forwarding references) at every stage.

Comment: unique or shared_ptr are good choices.  Bare pointer is always more difficult to track.

Comment: @Galik rvalue references don't "become lvalue-references" here. But you're correct that `std::move` is needed. It is needed because the id-expression `a` is an lvalue expression - regardless of the type of the expression which is rvalue reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can't move objects onto pointers (nullptr or otherwise). Nor can you extend the lifetime of objects by having pointers point to them - C++ simply doesn't work that way.

Since you need polymorphic behavior, you can't just copy-construct or assign an `Obj` pointer. You'll probably want something like a `clone()` method for class `Obj`, as discussed in this question:

[Copying derived entities using only base class pointers, (without exhaustive testing!) - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027456/copying-derived-entities-using-only-base-class-pointers-without-exhaustive-tes)

for more on this. Remember, though - you can't extend the rvalue reference's lifetime, so you have to construct a new object somehow. Also remember to avoid memory leakage. So if your `clone()` produces an `Obj*`, you'll need to write something like:

```
class Objpair {
   public:
      Objpair(Obj&& a, Obj&&b) : 
         first(a.clone()), 
         second(b.clone()) 
      { }
   private:
      std::unique_ptr<Obj> first;
      std::unique_ptr<Obj> second;
};
```

on perhaps [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)'s instead of the [`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)'s (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143936/1593077) about choosing between the two).

If you need "polymorphic" behavior, but you know the *exact* types of a and b at compile-time, and you don't mind having different `ObjPair` classes, you could also try something like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Objpair {
   public:
      Objpair(T1&& a, T2&&b) : first(a), second(b) 
      { }
   private:
      T1 first;
      T2 second;
};
```

in which case no pointers are involved (!)

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, you said,

> first and second can point to BaseClass, Derived1, Derived2,

In that case, your best option is to provide a `virtual` member function in `Obj` to clone an object.

```
class Obj
{
   public:
      virtual Obj* clone() const = 0;
   ...
}
```

and use it to initialize `first` and `second`.

```
 class Objpair {
   public:
      Objpair(Obj&& a, Obj&&b) : first(a.clone()), second(b.clone()) { }
   private:
       Obj* first;
       Obj* second;
};
```

and make sure that you take care of deallocating memory pointed to by `first` and `second` in the destructor. See [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for additional details.

You can use smart pointers to eliminate the need for code in your class for managing the life times of the objects. Whether you use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` depends on how you wish to use `Objpair`.

Answer (score 0):

@Galik's accepted answer is good. Though it requires that `Obj` is at least movable, which is similar to other answers with `Clone()` solutions - they all put some requirements on `Obj` and its descendants. To remove this restriction we can change `Objpair`'s constructor to accept `std::unique_ptr<Obj>`:

```
#include <memory>

class Obj
{
public:
    Obj() {}

    // non-copyable/non-movable
    Obj(const Obj&) = delete;
    Obj& operator=(const Obj&) = delete;
};

class Objpair {
   public:
      Objpair(std::unique_ptr<Obj>&& a, std::unique_ptr<Obj>&& b)
      : first(std::move(a))
      , second(std::move(b))
      {}

   private:
       std::unique_ptr<Obj> first;
       std::unique_ptr<Obj> second;
};

int main()
{
    Objpair p{std::make_unique<Obj>(), std::make_unique<Obj>()};
    return 0;
}
```

Possible bonuses are:

- user deals with memory allocation, and so has better control over it.
- user can use instances of `a` and `b` parameters before passing them to `Objpair`, polymorphically.